# AngluarJS $timeout not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout

I'm trying to create a delayed action in my view.
When a button is clicked, a corresponding message appears, however I want the message to disappear in 2000ms.
I found some cases where `$timeout` was recommended and I have seemingly followed the solutions in these cases, however the label text is not altered by the `$timeout` function.

Why is the my `$timeout` not functioning in this case?

I appreciate any guidance on the matter. Please find my code below.

// app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

// mainController.js

```
app.controller("mainController", ["$scope", function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.fireTrigger = function(str) {
    $scope.triggeredValue = (str) + " fired";
    $timeout(function() { 
            $scope.triggeredValue = "";
        }, 2000);
  }
}]);
```

// index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
<title>myApp</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="entertainment.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainController">
    <h3 ng-bind="triggeredValue"></h3>
// ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject dependency in inline array, before using it in factory function of controller

```
app.controller("mainController", ["$scope", "$timeout", //<-- add $timeout dependency
   function($scope, $timeout) {
```

Comment: Thank you youre right, I also noticed that I had forgot to call the function itself, inside my onclick function.